# WINAPI Hook - determine whether a new directory was created

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, hook

Is there any way to create a callback that reacts after the user created a new folder in the explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different APIs that will let you recieve notifications about folders being created.

[SHChangeNotifyRegister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows you to see what folders are created in Explorer.
[FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx) will notify you of changes under a sub folder (although won't tell you what folder has been created).

You'll get the most detailed information from [ReadDirectoryChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but it's the most complicated to use.  This [blog entry](http://qualapps.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/understanding-readdirectorychangesw.html) has good details on the pros and cons of each.